# RollbackException after using @Service inside ConstraintValidator isValid() method

Tags: java, spring, exception, constraints, transactional

I am creating my custom validation annotation so I needed to create my own ConstraintValidator implementation class.

```
public class SomethingValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Annotation, String>{
    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    public boolean isValid(...){
        //here I need to use the service
        someService.someMethod();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in this class, in isValid method I need to use SomeService class that is annotated as @Service

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
    public Something someMethod(){
        // stuff
    }
}
```

My application flow is something like this:

1. User enters Register page, fills the form and hits Register
2. In the @Controller class I check if bindingResult.hasErrors()
3. IF ERRORS EXIST: return to the register page and displays error messages
4. IF ERRORS NOT EXIST: calls autowired someService instance in the @Controller class and saves the entity.

And the problem is, if in my ConstrainValidation class, in isValid method I use someService then I receive RollbackException, even if the return is always true (statically added as in the code snipped above)

**So finally:** *I cant use SomeService inside isValid method, because it results with RollbackException* (stacktrace below)
Everything seems to work properly, but using the SomeService.

I know that the problem may be transactions, maybe I manage EntityManager wrong? or should I add any arguments to @Transactional method inside Service?

I am using Spring Data JPA and JpaRepository (so I dont obtain the @PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager)

I will very appreciate any kind of help..

Stacktraces: (I will paste all of it into pastebin) http://pastebin.com/FTjD5gRR